# Similar function in PHP for css @media?

Tags: php

In css we can use @media to (de)activate codes depending on the screen-width.
I was wondering if PHP has a similar function?

For example: If I would like the code below to only be active below 992px, how would this be done? Or do I have to stick to css edits in order to make this work...

```
// Move WooCommerce Single Sharing
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 30 );
```

Thanks in advance for you advice!

Comment: PHP runs on the server side and does not generally have access to the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery for execute php code in screen resolution.

```
if( $(window).width() > 992 )
{
  $.ajax({
  url: 'js/nbw-parallax.js',
  dataType: "script",
  success: function() {
    //success
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dhaval, I didn't know that was possible. But if I can't do it in PHP, I think it's best to stick to css... nice answer though. :) Have a great day!